# How to check and update table #1 data from table #2?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, sql-server-2014, database-administration

I have 2 table in my database.

Table #1

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| name | family | phone | email | gender | phone2 | address | birthdate |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Table #2

```
-----------------------------------------
| gender | address | phone | birthdate |
-----------------------------------------
```

in table #1 columns address and phone2 is empty and columns gender and birthdate values is same as table #2.

How can I read data from table #2 and update address and phone2 in table #1 with values from table #2 address and phone columns when gender and birthdate is the same in each row?

for example:
this is some data in Table #1

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| name | family | phone | email | gender | phone2 | address | birthdate |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| john | doe    | 12345| t@t.com| Male  |         |         | 1980-01-01|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| mike | clark  | 65432| x@y.com| Male  |         |         | 1990-01-01|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sara | King   | 875465| a@b.com|Female|         |         | 1970-01-01|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and here is some data in table #2

```
-----------------------------------------
| gender | address | phone | birthdate  |
-----------------------------------------
| Male   | 1704test|0457852|1980-01-01  |
-----------------------------------------
| Female | 1705abcs|0986532|1970-01-01  |
-----------------------------------------
| Male   | 1602cyzd|0326589|1990-01-01  |
-----------------------------------------
```

I want to update table #1 with data from table #2 and check gender and birthdate and make table #1 like

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| name | family | phone | email | gender | phone2 | address | birthdate |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| john | doe    | 12345| t@t.com| Male   |0457852 |1704test | 1980-01-01|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| mike | clark  | 65432| x@y.com| Male   |0326589  |1602cyzd| 1990-01-01|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sara | King   | 875465| a@b.com|Female |0986532  |1705abcs| 1970-01-01|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please don't crosspost your questions

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `JOIN` in an update statement.

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.phone2 = t2.phone, t1.address = t2.address
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 on t1.gender = t2.gender and t1.birthdate = t2.birthdate
```